# Not able to connect to websocket service using JMeter WebSocket Samplers plugin

Tags: websocket, jmeter

Trying to connect to websocker server using [JMeter WebSocket Samplers plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbXVP.png), but getting below response error.

Response code:418
Response message:Got unexpected status 418 with statusLine:HTTP/1.0 418 Unknown Code

Answer (score 0):

As per [HTTP Status Code 418](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/418) definition the error occurs when you use [Hyper Text Coffee Pot Control Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_Text_Coffee_Pot_Control_Protocol) to manipulate the teapot, double check your `${BASE_URL_1}` variable value and make sure that it is pointing to the coffee pot, not the tea pot.

Now seriously: we cannot diagnose the issue by looking at the incomplete low-res screenshot so I can provide only a generic piece of advice:

0. Double check that all these variables used in the request like `${connectionId}`, `${token}`, etc. have their anticipated values using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)
1. Use "network" tab of your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) (or as [sniffer tool](https://www.dnsstuff.com/packet-sniffers)) to capture the successful request from browser (or other application)
2. Use [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) (or again a sniffer tool) to capture the failing request from JMeter
3. Compare the requests, identify the differences, amend JMeter configuration so it would send **exactly the same request as the browser does** (apart from dynamic values which have to be [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/))
4. Once you send the same request you should get the same response instead of this funny 1st-April error message

Comment: Thanks for response Dmitri. Cross verified request in developer tool and jmeter request, it exactly same except port.Request in develpoer tool:
Request URL: wss://wcserver.abc.uk/testhub?transactionId=5fdb84f6-977a-4eff-ab02-758b839907ff&id==UOnPMna3X1IVv4xzkARvow&access_token=ey....

Jmeter request:
Connect URL:
wss://wcserver.abc.uk:443/testhub?transactionId=49734d81-0374-4560-9690-38b8c31141c0&id=gV-XO-Blnf904WYZ-HiB9Q&access_token=ey...

only difference i could see port 443. All corelation values are also correct.

Comment: So continue with step 1, 2 and 3. Really, this is the only sensible thing to do. Obviously, your test plan is sending something the server does not like. So if the server does not tell you what it doesn't like exactly (you did check server logs, didn't you?), the only to find out is to compare the failing request with a successful request.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully Open the WebSocket Connection. Initially i was also getting Bad Request in JMETER but in POSTMAN it was success. First I doubted port no. because POSTMAN was not sending any port in the request while JMETER was not ready send request without port (mandatory field). Then i added port 443 at both the places. POSTMAN was still able to send request successfully.

Then compared the request from both tools carefully and noticed that POSTMAN was sending %20 between "bearer" and and token string like this:
**accessToken=bearer%20eyJ0eXAi...** , while websocket sampler in JMETER was just sending white space which server was not accepting.

Then i added %20 in jmeter request and the server welcomed it with bot hands and gave green signal.

**Solution:** Just add %20 in Jmeter Samapler as i did , shown in below snapshot
[JMETER websocket sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s92Wt.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).